# Search results does not match all tableview data

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, custom-cell

I'm using tableview with custom cell contains label and sender(button) , I have data on that tableview and when I make a search i got match results on the label only the sender(button) always match the first field on that table view before the search operation,and when i press that button the button toke an action with the first object in tableview before the search operation not the searched item.What I'm asking is how to make the search results match the custom cell content in label and the sender status in the same time ,I'm using swift 2.0 x code 7.1 ...
Thanks

Comment: Might want to take another stab at the wording of the question or perhaps provide a concrete example - it's not easy to determine what you are after

Comment: Sir i have tableview contains a names of locations and i have a button asking the user to (share) and the title of that button changes to (shared )when the user tapped on that button  . for example that location is in the top of my tableview , the first object in my table . when i search for another location the result be just like the searched name but the button title changes to (Shared) while the button title must be (Share) @Paul.s